# How to define a parameter of type generic list with constructor constraint?

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to define three base classes, `TMyBaseClass` that keeps data, `TMyBaseClassList` that holds a list of instances of `TMyBaseClass`, and `TMyBaseClassReader` that scrolls through a dataset and fills a `TMyBaseClassList` object. This is my code:

```
  TMyBaseClass = class
  public
    // properties
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TMyBaseClassList<T: TMyBaseClass, constructor> = class(TObjectList<TMyBaseClass>)
  public
    function AddNew: T;
  end;

  TMyBaseClassReader<T: TMyBaseClass> = class
  public
    class procedure ReadProperties(const DataSet: TCustomADODataSet;
      const Item: T); virtual; abstract;
    class procedure ReadDataSet(const DataSet: TCustomADODataSet;
      const List: TMyBaseClassList<T>);// <- E2513
  end;

...

constructor TMyBaseClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TMyBaseClassList<T>.AddNew: T;
begin
  Result := T.Create;
  Add(Result);
end;

class procedure TMyBaseClassReader<T>.ReadDataSet;
var
  NewItem: T;
begin
  while not DataSet.Eof do
  begin
    NewItem := List.AddNew;
    ReadProperties(DataSet, NewItem);
    DataSet.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Then I want to derive child classes and only implement `ReadProperties` method. But I'm getting an E2513 error:

> E2513 Type parameter 'T' must have one public parameterless constructor named Create

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why did you use class abstract? What do you think that achieves?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean `ReadProperties`? I want to override it in `TMyBaseClassReader<TMyChildClass>`, then I wont replicate logic of `ReadDataSet` in all subclasses.

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry, that one was left from my original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that the compiler cannot be sure that T meets the requirements. Declare the derived class like so

```
TMyBaseClassReader<T: TMyBaseClass, constructor>
```